# Embedded views and localization

Tags: .net, razor, embedded-resource, class-library

I got some generic razor (view engine) views in a class library that I want to load through a `VirtualPathProvider`.

Everything works great unless I add `.sv` or `.en` to the view names (for example `MyView.en.cshtml`). By doing so it seems like Visual Studio compiles the views into resource DLLs.

Can I prevent that?

Having to load resource DLL's in my VirtualPathProvider seems like a hassle.
One thread might want to access Swedish views while the other want's English views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the views to `XXXXX._langCode.cshtml` (as in `details._sv.cshtml`). I then renamed them back in my `VirtualPathProvider` before returning them.

Works, but not really a solution to the problem.